# JSONB in where clause postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I Have a data like this -
[image: JSONB Data]

So i need to find out all rows with id=203498. How can i write a query for this ?
Any Help ?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the JSON containment operator `@>`:

```
WHERE jsoncol @> '[ { "id": 203498 }]';
```

Comment: `[{ "id": 203498 }]`

Comment: Is there any query which can update value of specific key in JSONB, based on condition ?

Comment: Is there any way in json columns to search for multiple values like IN operator?

Comment: @Sk.Irfan Sure, use `<@ ANY`. But you cannot index that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe

`@Query(value = "select * from conversations where meta\\:\\:jsonb @> :query", nativeQuery = true)`

I am using JPA query something like this and it fails, can you help?

query:
`any(array['{"reference": {"chartId": "1"}}', '{"reference": {"chartId": "2"}}']::jsonb[])`

Answer (score 3):

It depends your data so please add to example data but I will give you example data.

If your data like this

```
 id |                                     cars_info                                      
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"id": 1, "sold": true, "brand": "Toyota", "color": ["red", "black"], "price": 285000}
  2 | {"id": 2, "sold": false, "brand": "Honda", "color": ["blue", "pink"], "price": 25000}
  3 | {"id": 3, "sold": true, "brand": "Mitsubishi", "color": ["black", "gray"], "price": 604520}
```

Your query is like this. Maybe it can occurs some errors but your query will be seem like that.

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cars_info -> 'id' = '1';
```

Comment: Note that there is an extra array in the data.

Comment: Here is the exaple of the data that i have -

Comment: user_id | cases
abc | [
    {
        "id": "207226",
        "name": null,
        "type": "ChangeRequest"
    },
    {
        "id": "207225",
        "name": null,
        "type": "ChangeRequest"
    }
]